# tomcat process exists , after doing shutdown

Tags: tomcat

I am having Fedora 14  in my machine. When I do shutdown my tomcat server , the process is not getting killed. Then i manually kill the process . I do the following to do shutdown

> CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh

When i type ,

ps -eaf | grep -i tomcat

It shows a unkilled tomcat process.

Does anyone know the reason for this . . ?

Comment: am using   apache-tomcat 6.0.32  , in  my Fedora 14 linux machine

Comment: is there a web application deployed in that tomcat? What do the tomcat logs show? How do you start that tomcat?

Comment: yes there is a web application deployed. tomcat log reports about some memory leak , that was created by application . I start tomcat as follow ,   CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh

Comment: ok, judging from your last comment, the application that is deployed does not shutdown nicely and that is why tomcat cannot shutdown nicely either. Do you have control over that application, ie do you have the sources? The tomcat log may contain more precise info to help you track down the source of the problem. Often times these problems can be tracked down to resource pools (eg database).

Comment: yes its a problem in my application. thanks